# How to get all jobs that user has not applied to in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have to tables, `job_postings` and `job_applies`. How can I get all the jobs, that user has not applied to?

Below are columns of my `job_postings` table:

```
id, user_id, title, description, duties, salary, child_count, benefits, created_at, updated_at
```

Below are columns of the `job_applies` table

```
user_id, posting_id, status, created_at, updated_at
```

What I tried:

```
  $job_postings =  DB::table('job_postings')
        ->select(
          'job_postings.title',
          'job_postings.description',
          'job_postings.duties',
          'job_postings.salary',
          'job_postings.child_count',
          'job_postings.benefits',
          'job_postings.created_at',
          'job_postings.id AS posting_id',
          'job_postings.user_id')
        ->join('job_applies', 'job_applies.posting_id', '!=', 'job_postings.id')
        ->where('job_applies.user_id', "=" , user()->id)
        ->get();
```

Comment: What does the user_id in job_postings mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mysql you should write  (replace * with your field list).  You can adapt to your language

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM JOB_POSTING A
 LEFT JOIN JOB_APPLIES B ON B.POSTING_ID = A.ID AND B.USER_ID = A.USER_ID
 WHERE B.POSTING_ID IS NULL
```

or

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM JOB_POSTING A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM JOB_APPLIES B WHERE B.POSTING_ID = A.ID  AND B.USER_ID = A.USER_ID)
```