# How to get all advertisements that user has not applied to

Tags: mysql

I did not know if I should have edited to old question since the answer worked for me yesterday, but due to some changes it does not anymore. Referring to this: [How to get all jobs that user has not applied to in mySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185485/how-to-get-all-jobs-that-user-has-not-applied-to-in-mysql)

I have to tables, `job_postings` and `job_applies`. How can I get all the jobs, that user has not applied to?

Below are columns of my `job_postings` table:

```
id, user_id, title, description, duties, salary, child_count, benefits, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
```

Below are columns of the `job_applies` table

```
user_id, posting_id, status, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
```

What I tried:

```
    $job_postings =  DB::table('job_postings')
        ->select(
          'job_postings.title',
          'job_postings.description',
          'job_postings.duties',
          'job_postings.salary',
          'job_postings.child_count',
          'job_postings.benefits',
          'job_postings.created_at',
          'job_postings.id AS posting_id',
          'job_applies.status')
        ->leftJoin('job_applies', function($join)
          {
              $join->on('job_applies.posting_id', '=', 'job_postings.id')
              ->on('job_applies.user_id', '=', 'job_postings.user_id');
          })
          ->where('job_applies.status', "!=", 1)
          ->whereNull('job_postings.deleted_at')
          ->whereNull('job_applies.posting_id')
        ->get();
```

But this gives me 0 results. Currently there's two job application with `id = 1` and `id = 2`
and one job apply for the application with `id = 1`. `job_applies.status = 1` means that user has applied to that job.

### EDIT

For clarification, if the user un-applies the job, it will update the `status` to 4, which means cancelled and so the rows are actually never deleted from the job_applies table.

The query above still gives me 0 results. How can I get the jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Allow null value to status column as well.

```
   $job_postings =  DB::table('job_postings')
            ->select(
              'job_postings.title',
              'job_postings.description',
              'job_postings.duties',
              'job_postings.salary',
              'job_postings.child_count',
              'job_postings.benefits',
              'job_postings.created_at',
              'job_postings.id AS posting_id',
              'job_applies.status')
            ->innerJoin('job_applies', function($join)
              {
                  $join->on('job_applies.posting_id', '=', 'job_postings.id')
                  ->on('job_applies.user_id', '=', 'job_postings.user_id');
              })
              ->where('job_applies.status', "!=", 1)
              ->whereNull('job_applies.status')
              ->whereNull('job_postings.deleted_at')
              ->whereNull('job_applies.posting_id')
            ->get();
```